# How to launch a JVM from C#

Tags: c#

I would like to launch a java application from C# but am unsure of the proper way to do it. I can do it from a bat file:

```
java -cp ".;other_classes_location" classname
```

How does this get turned into C#?

Comment: Check out `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fileName, arguments);`.

Comment: What is the actual problem you need to solve with Java?

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("classname", "-cp classpath");
where does the java go, or is it java.exe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have posted is a command line (likely executed in a command shell)

you **cannot** turn this into C# code

I guess you are looking for a way to execute that command using C#. In this case the answer is the below code

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("yourPath\java.exe", "Command Line Arguments");
```

Comment: great thanks for your help, ill give it a go, my first attempt ended in miserable failure

Comment: Thanks for the info, at least its starting now!

Answer (score 1):

Use Process.Start.
Examples [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/process-start).